# how to create a navigational app for blind people?

Tags: android

I am developing a navigational app to assist blind people as part of my project. I  should take source and destination address as voice inputs and output the path as voice output. I am just learning about android development. Can anyone tell me the steps i need to follow in developing this app..

Comment: You just listed them :) Get voice inputs, translate them into source and destinations, use those to get directions, and output those directions through the speaker. Look up how to do each of those individually and you have your app.

Comment: Should i use google maps api ?

Comment: I don't think blind people use smart phones. Even if they do, they won't go to a place to which they are not familiar without anyones help. Better to search for different project.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the input as voice when the blind user presses the volume up or down button because they don't know how to open app .

Comment: What other procedure should i follow after taking voice input. Will i be needing google maps api?

Comment: @nik yes you would be using Google maps API.

Comment: There is no need to use google map api because blind person can't see maps. Googleplayservices is can give you address without using maps.

Comment: @AmeerFaisal how can one get directions without maps? As far as I know Play services don't give you directions.

Comment: @rusted brain will i be able get voice output of direction? can you suggest me any websites that will help me in this project